# Trigger - Syntax Error #1064 new/old

Tags: mysql

What mistake did I make here?

```
CREATE TRIGGER total BEFORE UPDATE ON `current` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
if new.`new_pay_date` <> old.`new_pay_date`
  SET new.`total_cash` = new.`curr_cash` + new.`total_cash`;
end if;
END;
$$
```

Error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET new.`total_cash` = new.`curr_cash` + new.`total_cash`; end if;' at line 4
```

This was working without

```
if new.`new_pay_date` <> old.`new_pay_date`
end if;
```

But I need to check this, and only update with date change.

current table:

```
curr_cash
new_pay_date
id_person
id_thing
total_cash
```

Anyone can help me with this one?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `THEN` at the end of the if statement:

```
IF new.`new_pay_date` <> old.`new_pay_date` THEN
    SET new.`total_cash` = new.`curr_cash` + new.`total_cash`;
END IF;
```

Comment: See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html for reference